# Fpdf lines,multicells,arrays

Tags: php, arrays, fpdf

I have no idea what I'm doing, but somehow I managed to get my code to get more or less what I want.  The problem is that I think I can make this simpler, but I'm not very bright in the coding department so I wouldn't know how to do it.  To explain, I need my pdf to look like this:

[image: How it should look]

That image I was able to get using this code:

```
function FirstPageLines() {
    $this - > SetFont('Arial2', '', 7);
    $arrComponents = array("Milk", "Grains", "Vegetables", "Fruits", "Meats");
    $arrMilk = array("Fat Free", "Low Fat", "Yogurt");
    $arrGrains = array("Crackers", "Cookies", "Bread");
    $arrVegs = array("Onion", "Lettuce", "Carrot");
    $arrFruits = array("Pineapple", "Orange", "Grape");
    $arrMeats = array("Chicken", "Fajitas", "Pork", "Ribs");

    $yLine = 10;
    $xLine = 33;
    $yText = 20;
    ///////////////////////////Milk Section///////////////////////////// 
    $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this - > SetXY(10, 10);
    $this - > SetFillColor(160, 160, 160); //set fill color to grey
    $this - > MultiCell(590, 14, "Milks", 1, 'L', 1);
    $this - > Ln();

    $length = count($arrMilk);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        $this - > Text($xLine, $yLine + 24, $arrMilk[$i]);
        $this - > Line($xLine, $yLine + 25, 600, $yLine + 25);
        $yText = $yText + 50;
        $yLine = $yLine + 13;
    }

    ///////////////////////////Grains Section///////////////////////////// 
    $this - > Ln();
    $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this - > SetXY($xLine - 20, $yLine + 20);
    $this - > SetFillColor(160, 160, 160); //set fill color to grey
    $this - > MultiCell(590, 14, "Grains", 1, 'L', 1);

    $length = count($arrGrains);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this - > Ln();
        $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        $this - > Text($xLine, $yLine + 45, $arrGrains[$i]);
        $this - > Line($xLine, $yLine + 45, 600, $yLine + 45);
        $yText = $yText + 50;
        $yLine = $yLine + 13;
    }
    ////////////////////////Vegetables Section/////////////////////////////
    $this - > Ln();
    $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this - > SetXY($xLine - 20, $yLine + 40);
    $this - > SetFillColor(160, 160, 160); //set fill color to grey
    $this - > MultiCell(590, 14, "Vegetables", 1, 'L', 1);

    $length = count($arrVegs);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this - > Ln();
        $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        $this - > Text($xLine, $yLine + 65, $arrVegs[$i]);
        $this - > Line($xLine, $yLine + 65, 600, $yLine + 65);
        $yText = $yText + 50;
        $yLine = $yLine + 13;
    }
    /////////////////////////Fruits Section/////////////////////////////             
    $this - > Ln();
    $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this - > SetXY($xLine - 20, $yLine + 60);
    $this - > SetFillColor(160, 160, 160); //set fill color to grey
    $this - > MultiCell(590, 14, "Fruits", 1, 'L', 1);

    $length = count($arrFruits);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this - > Ln();
        $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        $this - > Text($xLine, $yLine + 85, $arrFruits[$i]);
        $this - > Line($xLine, $yLine + 85, 600, $yLine + 85);
        $yText = $yText + 50;
        $yLine = $yLine + 13;
    }
    //////////////////////////Meats Section/////////////////////////////      
    $this - > Ln();
    $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
    $this - > SetXY($xLine - 20, $yLine + 80);
    $this - > SetFillColor(160, 160, 160); //set fill color to grey
    $this - > MultiCell(590, 14, "Meats", 1, 'L', 1);

    $length = count($arrMeats);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $this - > Ln();
        $this - > SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        $this - > Text($xLine, $yLine + 105, $arrMeats[$i]);
        $this - > Line($xLine, $yLine + 105, 600, $yLine + 105);
        $yText = $yText + 50;
        $yLine = $yLine + 13;
    }
```

So, my question is this:  I want to use the array at the top with the components `$arrComponents=array("Milk","Grains","Vegetables","Fruits","Meats");`

instead of having to individually write each header in the grey boxes.  I would also like for the other arrays to populate under the appropriate headers (Milk items under milk header; grains under grain header, etc).  I would also like for no header to show up if there are no items, as sometimes clients might not need any milk, but only one or two of the other components.  Finally, I tested my code to see what happens when there are various items in the arrays, and I noticed that once the items fill up one page, the next page stops showing items under the headers.  The headers show up, but not the items under them.  I know I could also use some help cleaning this code up so it won't be so messy.

Answer (score 2):

Define your components using an associative array.

```
$components = array(
    "Milk" => array("Fat Free", "Low Fat", "Yogurt"),
    "Grains" => array("Crackers", "Cookies", "Bread"),
    "Vegetables" => array("Onion", "Lettuce", "Carrot"),
    "Fruits" => array("Pineapple", "Orange", "Grape"),
    "Meats" => array("Chicken", "Fajitas", "Pork", "Ribs")
);
```

It looks like you've already created a subclass of FPDF. Good! Let's add a way to pass our associative array to that subclass.

```
class MRod_FPDF extends FPDF {
    var $components;

    function SetComponents($components) {
        $this->components = $components;
    }
}
```

Adding the grey header box is a repetitive task, so let's move that code to a method of its own:

```
    function AddComponentHeader($component) {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->SetFillColor(160, 160, 160);
        $this->MultiCell(190, 12, $component, 1, 'L', 1);
    }
```

Adding the items for each component is also a repetitive task, so let's create a method for that. (I've also added a variable for the X offset of each item.)

Note that I used `MultiCell` instead of `Text` to save myself the hassle of dealing with coordinates, which makes the code more reliable in the cases when the contents of the document that we're creating extend to more than one page.

```
    var $itemX = 30;

    function AddItems($items) {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->SetX($this->itemX);
            $this->MultiCell(167, 8, $item);
            $y = $this->GetY();
            $this->Line($this->itemX, $y, 200, $y);
        }
        $this->Ln(5);
    }
```

Your `FirstPageLines` method is now as simple as this:

```
    function FirstPageLines() {
        foreach ($this->components as $component => $items) {
            if (!empty($items)) {
                $this->AddComponentHeader($component);
                $this->AddItems($items);
            }
        }
    }
```

Find the full code [here](https://gist.github.com/mwiehl/58d9d9186c03fca4c463b3b0ae30f5d9).

Comment: Wow!  That was so simple, and I knew it was possible, but I just have trouble thinking outside the box.  I hope you don't mind me asking one question.  What is this code here doing?
 function AddItems($items) {
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'I', 11);
        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $this->SetX($this->itemX);

Where did $items come from?  I don't see it mentioned anywhere else.  I also don't know what it is doing.  Sorry if this is such a simple question, but I want to make sure I understand what is going on.  Thank you :)

Comment: It defines a method (which in PHP is a function used in the context of a class) named `AddItems`. That method takes a parameter named `$items`, and is called by the the `FirstPageLines` method which passes it an array. The `foreach` loop iterates over that array.